# in C#, Append selection multiple times from 2 ComboBoxes into a TextBox using a button

Tags: c#, combobox, textbox, append

I am trying to append selections from 2 ComboBoxes into a TextBox with a click of a button and I am not sure how to do this. I can do it once with code like this:

```
 private void BTN_APPEND_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TB_CONNECTORS.Text = CB_PORT_NUMBER.Text + " " + CB_CONNECTOR.Text;
    }
```

And this will result in
[Append with the click of a button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsEOS.jpg)

but the question is, how can I append to this one more time?

Comment: what do you mean one more time ? give an example ?

Comment: Just add a plus sign + in front of the equals sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this :

```
 if(!TB_CONNECTORS.Text == "")
 {
 TB_CONNECTORS.Text = TB_CONNECTORS.Text + " & " + CB_PORT_NUMBER.Text + " " + CB_CONNECTOR.Text;
 }
 else
 {
 TB_CONNECTORS.Text = CB_PORT_NUMBER.Text + " " + CB_CONNECTOR.Text;
 }
```

This will result in the new value achieved from the 2 comboboxes keeping the existing text of the textbox

Comment: That worked... Is there a way to add "&" between the two items (since I only need to do this twice)?

Comment: @jbegic of course, please make sure to mark the answer as answer and recheck my code

Comment: Thank you :-)... The only issue is that it will look like this: "&2 RJ45&2 QSFP28". I wanted to be "2 RJ45 & 2 QSFP28"

Comment: @jbegic , recheck my code and make sure to mark it as the answer :)